# Android Studio not working: it is showing on background but not launching in home screen

Tags: android, android-studio, ubuntu

I have tried to install Android studio in my Ubuntu 16.04 but it is not working   it is showing on background but not launching in home screen.

Comment: what's "showing on background"?

Answer (score 0):

Try to run `studio.sh` file using terminal like                                    `/home/developer/AndroidStudio_3.0/android-studio/bin/studio.sh`